# Pass Query in Sub Report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a Asp.net-crystal report in which i am using 2 sub reports.
 I am passing the following query to my main report:

```
select * from VW_Report_PIGroup where Lc_No='NIB12INSU9001005253'
```

I need to pass remaining part of query in 2 sub reports, and the query is:

```
1st Sub report=> and Group_Type ='PerfInv'  
2nd Sub report=> and Group_Type = 'Charges'
```

Help me passing remaining part of query in sub reports

Answer (score 0):

Into each sub-report:
 - Go to `Database Expert` \ `Edit command` (or create if you haven't yet)
 - Create a parameter, name it `QueryBegin`
 - Double click on the parameter and type the rest o the query, so that you should have this Command:     `{?BeginReport} and Group_Type ='PerfInv'`

Now in the Main Report:
 - Right-click on subreports, then `Change Sub-Report Links`
 - Pass to `BeginReport` parameter the first part of the query, taking it from where it's stored